# How to get the permanent token for Shopify (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, shopify

I am trying to authenticate my new Shopify app. First, my `authenticate` method redirects the shop owner to Shopify's authentication page:

```
def authenticate
  ShopifyAPI::Session.setup({:api_key => "123", :secret => "456"})
  session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new("someshop.myshopify.com")
  redirect_to session.create_permission_url(["read_orders"], "https://myapp.com/shopify/post_authenticate?user=someshop")
end
```

Once the shop owner has approved the integration, the redirect uri triggers my `post_authenticate` method:

```
def post_authenticate
  ShopifyAPI::Session.setup({:api_key => "123", :secret => "456"})
  session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new("#{params[:user]}.myshopify.com")
  token = session.request_token(:code => params[:code], :signature => params[:signature], :timestamp => params[:timestamp])
end
```

But the `request_token` method returns the following error:

```
#<ShopifyAPI::ValidationException: Invalid Signature: Possible malicious login>
```

I have read somewhere that you need to be in the same `ShopifyAPI` session while doing all of this, but it does not say so in the [documentation](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api). And the [example app](https://github.com/shopify/shopify_app) takes a very different approach than the documentation.

Comment: Are you using the older method for authorizing? I'm using omniauth in my app

Comment: Hi @agmcleod. I thought that the authorization was a part of the `shopify_api` gem. I have not installed any additional authentication gems.

Comment: Yeah they used to have an older method that was deprecated in favour of using OAuth. https://github.com/Shopify/omniauth-shopify-oauth2 is the gem I use. I'll post an answer with how i utilize it.

Comment: Arg. So I have spend a whole day debugging on an old gem. Very nice. But thanks for making a post on how to use it. Much appreciated!

Comment: The shopify_api gem allows you to make api requests, so it's far from useless. Just need to make requests on behalf of a shop, you need to have the shop owner authenticate first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, I utilize the omniauth methodology for authenticating. Here's a gist of the code for reference. https://gist.github.com/agmcleod/7106363317ebd082d3df. Put all the snippets below.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  force_ssl
  helper_method :current_shop, :shopify_session

protected

  def current_shop
    @current_shop ||= Shop.find(session[:shop_id]) if session[:shop_id].present?
  end

  def shopify_session
    if current_shop.nil?
      redirect_to new_login_url
    else
      begin
        session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(current_shop.url, current_shop.token)
        ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session)
        yield
      ensure
        ShopifyAPI::Base.clear_session
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In my login controller:

```
def create
  omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  if omniauth && omniauth[:provider] && omniauth[:provider] == "shopify"
    shop = Shop.find_or_create_by_url(params[:shop].gsub(/https?\:\/\//, ""))
    shop.update_attribute(:token, omniauth['credentials'].token)
    shopify_session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(shop.url, shop.token)
    session[:shop_id] = shop.to_param
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:error] = "Something went wrong"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :shopify, Settings.api_key, Settings.api_secret,
    scope: 'write_products,write_script_tags,read_orders',
    setup: lambda { |env| params = Rack::Utils.parse_query(env['QUERY_STRING'])
                        env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_options][:site] = "http://#{params['shop']}" }
end
```

Then in your routes file, map the create action of your session appropriately:

```
match '/auth/shopify/callback', :to => 'login#create'
```

From there i use the shopify_session method as an around filter on the appropriate controllers.